# How to disable Django Internal function cache?

Tags: python, django, caching, runtime, redis

I'm making some Django projects using Redis as Backend Cache[1], but I can't be sure that the Redis Server will be On all the time, then I'm trying to use Redis "if" it's available otherwise use some other Backend like LocMem and so on.

The Redis Backend that I'm using[1] is full compatible so I can use Django Decorations.

I was think to create a function to be called like that:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from utils import PingBackend
from time import time

@cache_page(60, cache=PingBackend(time()))
def index(request):

    artigos = Artigo.objects.filter(ativo=1)

    return render_to_response('index.html', {'artigos':artigos}, RequestContext(request))
```

The problem is that Django (Internals I guess) Caches the response of PingBackend() and call it just the first time, even if I drop the RedisServer Django tells that the ping process was successfully.

It occurs even with DEBUG=True and 'default' CacheBackend to dummy.

```
def PingBackend(time):
    print time

    response = None

    try:
        con = StrictRedis(host=settings.REDIS_HOST, port=settings.REDIS_PORT, db=0)

        # Execute some action
        con.ping()

        # If not give an exception, use redis
        response = 'redis'

    except:
        response = 'default' #dummy

    return last_response
```

I'm passing time() just to create some differentiation as a try solve the cache problm.

The big picture is that the function PingBackend() aren't executing for each request, just for the first the I can't monitor the Redis Server.

Thank you!

[1] - https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis

Answer (score 3):

This is not about Django internals, this is about how decorators work.  When you define your view like this:

```
@cache_page(60, cache=PingBackend(time()))
def index(request):
    blah blah
```

it is exactly equivalent to this:

```
def index(request):
    blah blah
index = cache_page(60, cache=PingBackend(time()))(index)
```

You are invoking `cache_page` only one, passing it a `cache` argument that you got by invoking `PingBackend` once.  It isn't even executing just for the first request, it is executing once when the view function is defined.

You should write your own cache backend that uses Redis if it's available, or something else if it is not.

Comment: Thank you very much, I guess that you are right about it, cya!